# //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, powerdns

make powerdns it give error don't know how to resolve it

error   CXX      epollmplexer.o
CXXLD    dnsdist
/usr/bin/ld: libssl.o: undefined reference to symbol 'CRYPTO_get_ex_new_index@@OPENSSL_1_1_0'

//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Makefile:1206: recipe for target 'dnsdist' failed

make[2]: *** [dnsdist] Error 1

make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/pdns/pdns/dnsdistdist'

Makefile:1443: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed

make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/pdns/pdns/dnsdistdist'

Makefile:1077: recipe for target 'all' failed

make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Please edit your question to (a) format it properly, and (b) include the link line that caused the warning to be printed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add "-lcrypto" to your linker command.